# How can you have Composer install the site in the project root not in web/?

Tags: 8, composer

I have downloaded Drupal 8.8 through composer drupal/recommended-project. The downloaded files structure is diff than previous download. Now core and other files are stored in web folder and vendor is out of core.

So my question is how to setup site in public_html/. I have uploaded files entire files under public_html/ but site not works. I also tried to access example.com/web but does't work.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Follow the instructions in `/core/UPDATE.txt` for non-composer sites. Once you have updated to Drupal 8.8 there are plans to make it much easier to switch to composer based updates, see the official update docs.

Answer (score 0):

If the server you are using uses public_html as document root, and not web as drupal/recommended-project expects, you need to follow what reported in [Using Composer to Install Drupal and Manage Dependencies](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies).

> If you want to modify some of the properties of the downloaded composer.json before composer install is executed, use the `--no-install` flag when running `composer create-project`. For example, it is possible that you want to rename the subdirectory 'web' to something else.
>
> To do that:
>
> 1. Run `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project my_site_name_dir --no-interaction --no-install`
> 2. Change directories to my_site_name_dir and edit the composer.json file to suit your needs
> 3. Run `composer install` to download Drupal 8 and all its dependencies.

Comment: I have edit composer.json and change web-root to ./ and also edit installer paths. Now all files downloaded in same directory. Which I upload in public_html and setup the site successfully.

Is there any security issue by drupal ? If i setup all private files/folder (vendor) in web accessible directory (I mean public_html)

Comment: If the document root folder is public_html. then you need to replace _web_ with *public_html*, in the composer.json file.